# ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") not working for me

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I want to add names of files of a specific folder to an JS's array, but nothing happens:

```
var pics = new Array();

var x;
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
alert('x');
var fo = fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("C:\wamp\www\newsite\ErfanGhiasiPanel\Slider Images"));
for (x in fo.files){
    pics.push(x.Name);
}
```

For instance, whet I insert an

```
alert('something')
```

after var fs = new ActiveXObject... or next lines, it won't appear.
What you guys think?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming JScript + Classic ASP due to the `MapPath` (which you dont need in your case) you need to escape the path string;

```
var pics = [];
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fo = new Enumerator(fs.GetFolder("C:\\wamp\\www\\newsite\\ErfanGhiasiPanel\\Slider Images").Files);

for (; !fo.atEnd(); fo.moveNext()) {
    pics.push(fo.item(0).Name)
}
```