# Accessing Local File System in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

I have tried a lot to access local file system on internet explorer. I have got some script after googling. This can be achieved through creating a `ActiveXObject` on internet Explorer. But for security reason  internet explorer by default disable this option. If someone chnage it it would be possible. My Question is is there any other way to access locla file system in Internet Explorer without changing the browser setting manually?

I want to use this for pre upload file size checking program. I cant use FLASH on this page to achieve this.

Comment: If this was possible, IE would be very dangerous to use. Keep searching.

Comment: can you share the script you found anyway ?

Comment: [Reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258491/var-f-new-activexobjectscripting-filesystemobject-not-working-with-ie8),[Reference 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823136/activexobjectscripting-filesystemobject-not-working-for-me)

Answer (score 1):

Would not be fun if you enter a website and it steal your things from your file system. It's a high security issue, this is why it's blocked and can't be automatically unblocked.

However, if you only need to limit the file size limit, you can the hidden input `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in your form to limit the maximum file size.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000" />
```

Note that it works with PHP [as described here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/HTML_File_Uploads), if you are using an other server side language you need to check how to limit the file size in the language that you are using.

If you really need to access the file system and you are in a corporate environment you can change that setting using group policy (you'll need to talk with the network administrator) to change that and make all your stations vulnerable to bad stuff in internet or create an extension that do the dangerous actions that you need only on your pages.

Comment: I know it is dangerous to use. Because Afterthat Anybody can get access of my local file system and even my commandline also.